# Perl Image Resize using GD and maintain image quality

Tags: image, perl, gd

I am trying to resize the image using GD image library and perl, but when it is resized the quality of image is not same as original uploaded image.. Do you guys have any suggestion?

Below is my code

```
my $dest_w = $width;
my $dest_h = $width * ($h / $w);

my $dest = GD::Image->new($dest_w, $dest_h, 1);

$dest->copyResampled($src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $dest_w, $dest_h, $w, $h);

open OUT, ">$target" or die "Could not save to $target";
binmode OUT;
print OUT $img->jpeg($quality); 
close OUT;
```

Anything wrong with my code? thanks for advice

Note: I uploaded .png image. Even if uploaded .jpeg image, the quality of the image is also dropped

Comment: You're doing a no-op resize of a JPEG.  Yes, this is going to cause quality degredation, because it's a JPEG.

Comment: Hi Charles, what should I do with my code? thanks for advice

Comment: Save it as something that isn't lossy?

Comment: What's your *source* image type?  If it's a palette based image, the result will be worse than if it's a trueColor image.  You should set GD to default to trueColor images.

Comment: I tried .png and .jpeg image, both give me same result (bad image quality)..

Comment: @Lucky-OngOng: When you loaded the JPEG, did you tell GD to load it as trueColor?

Comment: yes... GD::Image->new($dest_w, $dest_h, 1);

parameter 1 is telling GD to load as true color

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use GD? If you use GD to resize an input image eg a .jpg in Perl even with

```
my $quality = 100;
print OUT $resultimage->jpeg($quality);
```

then at least in its present versions, as I have tested them just now, both GD and Imlib2 (also there quality set to 100) produced somewhat more blur than such as ImageMagick in Perl. In addition, best results come if resized jpg image is saved to .gif (or .png), eg:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use Image::Magick;
my($inimage, $resultimage, $info);
$inimage = Image::Magick->new;
$info = $inimage->Read('exampleimagebig.jpg');
warn "$info" if "$info";
$info = $inimage->Resize(geometry=>'500x500', blur=>0.9);
warn "$info" if "$info";
# In the next line you can write .png or if you must, .jpg:
$info = $inimage->Write('exampleimage500.gif');
warn "$info" if "$info";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try define $quality as in my example and try it with png on input.

```
binmode OUT;
$quality=100; 
print OUT $img->jpeg($quality);
```